# Javascript - recursively remove nodes of a certain type from tree, but reattach and spread eligible children

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, tree

I'm writing a recursive function on a JSON tree `{name, type, [children]}` to remove nodes of a certain type. However, the children of the removed node should get re-attached to the parent, if they are not of the type to be removed.

I'm experiencing the following difficulty:
Let's say I want to remove type b on the following tree:

```
const sampleData = [{
name: "parent",
type: "a",
children: [{
    name: "childA",
    type: "a",
    children: null
    },{
    name: "childB",
    type: "b",
    children: [{
        name: "grandChildA",
        type: "a",
        children: null
        },{
        name: "grandChildB",
        type: "a",
        children: null
        }]
    },{
    name: "childC",
    type: "a",
    children: null
    }]
}]
```

The original children for parent is `[childA, childB, childC]`.
After the removal, the parent should have children `[childA, grandChildA, grandChildB, childC]`.
However, the result I'm getting is `[childA, [grandChildA, grandChildB], childC]`.

I know I need to spread it out, but I'm not sure where to do it in the recusion.

Here's the function that I have right now (I know I'm using the spread syntax in the wrong place):

```
const removeType = (node, type) => {
    //if the node should not be removed    
    if (node.type !== type){
        //if the node has children, recursively call to prune children
        if (node.children && node.children.length > 0){
            node.children = [...node.children.map(child => removeType(child, type))
                                             .filter(child => child !== null)]
            return node
        }
        //if the node has no children, return the node
        else return node
    }
    //if the node should be removed
    else if (node.type === type){
        //if the node has children, recursively call, then reattach the children
        if (node.children && node.children.length > 0){
            node.children = [...node.children.map(child => removeType(child, type))
                                             .filter(child => child !== null)]
            return node.children
        }
        //
        else return null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

I think you can use reduce for that, I'm not having my computer right now to test it, but it'll be something like this

```
const removeType = (node, type) => {
   if (node === null) {
     return null;
   } else {
    return node.reduce((acc, child) => {
      if(child["type"] === type) {
        const removedChild = removeType(child["children"], type);
        acc = [...acc, ...removedChild];
      } else {
        child.children = removeType(child["children"], type);
        acc.push(child);
      }
      return acc;
    }, []);
  }
}
```

**2nd Update**

Code reduced:

```
const removeType = (node, type) => {
    if (!node) return;

    return node.reduce((acc, child) => {
        if(child["type"] === type) {
            const removedChild = removeType(child["children"], type);
            acc = [...acc, ...removedChild];
        } else {
            child.children = removeType(child["children"], type);
            acc.push(child);
        }
        return acc;
    }, []);

}
```

Comment: This returns `[childA, [grandChildA, grandChildB], childC]`, still has the nested array.

Comment: Thanks so much! I should've thought of using reduce lol.

Answer (score 2):

I think this answer is just enough different from the others supplied to add it as an alternative.  It has the same recursive structure as the answer from Thankyou, but it makes the simplifying assumption that your input is always an array, as are all non-nil `children` nodes.

```js
const removeType = (node, target) =>
  node .flatMap (({type, children, ...rest}) =>
    type === target
      ? children ? removeType (children, target) : []
      : [{...rest, type, children: children && (removeType (children, target))}]
  )

const sampleData = [{name: "parent", type: "a", children: [{name: "childA", type: "a", children: null},{name: "childB", type: "b", children: [{name: "grandChildA", type: "a", children: null},{name: "grandChildB", type: "a", children: null}]}, {name: "childC", type: "a", children: null}]}]

console .log (
 removeType (sampleData, 'b')
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

I'm not claiming this as an improvement on the other answers, but it is an interesting alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to simplify the program using `Array.prototype.flatMap`, some mathematical induction, and a dash of mutual recursion -

- `removeType` accepts an *array* of `nodes` and a query type to remove, `q`
- `removeType1` accepts a *single* `node` and a query type to remove, `q`

```js
const removeType = (nodes, q) =>
  (nodes || []).flatMap(n => removeType1(n, q))  // <-- removeType1

const removeType1 = (node, q) =>
  q === node.type
    ? removeType(node.children)                  // <-- removeType
    : { ...node, children: removeType(node.children, q) } // <-- removeType

const input = 
  [{name:"parent",type:"a",children:[{name:"childA",type:"a",children:null},{name:"childB",type:"b",children:[{name:"grandChildA",type:"a",children:null},{name:"grandChildB",type:"a",children:null}]},{name:"childC",type:"a",children:null}]}]
  
const result =
  removeType(input, "b")

console.log(result)
```

Output -

```
[
  {
    "name": "parent",
    "type": "a",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "childA",
        "type": "a",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "name": "grandChildA",
        "type": "a",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "name": "grandChildB",
        "type": "a",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "name": "childC",
        "type": "a",
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Note that `result` is a *new* object and that `input` is *not* mutated as a result of calling `removeType`.

---

Mutual recursion is a nice fit for the problem above, but what if you truly wanted just one function?

```js
const removeType = (t, q) =>
  Array.isArray(t)                             // <-- array
    ? t.flatMap(node => removeType(node, q))
: Object(t) === t                              // <-- object (node)
    ? q === t.type
        ? removeType(t.children, q)
        : { ...t, children: removeType(t.children, q) }
: t                                            // <-- else (no operation)

const input = 
  [{name:"parent",type:"a",children:[{name:"childA",type:"a",children:null},{name:"childB",type:"b",children:[{name:"grandChildA",type:"a",children:null},{name:"grandChildB",type:"a",children:null}]},{name:"childC",type:"a",children:null}]}]
  
const result =
  removeType(input, "b")

console.log(result)
```

Output is mostly the same except notice how this one preserves `children: null`. Our original program yields the more correct `children: []` -

```
[
  {
    "name": "parent",
    "type": "a",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "childA",
        "type": "a",
        "children": null
      },
      {
        "name": "grandChildA",
        "type": "a",
        "children": null
      },
      {
        "name": "grandChildB",
        "type": "a",
        "children": null
      },
      {
        "name": "childC",
        "type": "a",
        "children": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```