# filter nest tree object by object id

Tags: recursion, filter

I have a tree object like below:

```
let data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    children: [
     {
      id: 1.1,
      children: [
       {
        id: 1.2,
        children: []
       },
       {
        id: 1.22,
        children: []
        }
      ]
     }
    ]
  },
  {
   id: 2,
   children: []
  }
]
```

I want to filter out id equal a specific value. In this case, I want to filter out id equal **1.2**.

The rusult I want is like below:

```
let data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    children: [
     {
      id: 1.1,
      children: [
        {
         id: 1.22,
         children: []
        }
      ]
     }
    ]
  },
  {
   id: 2,
   children: []
  }
]
```

I have search a few question about filter nest deep object, But still don't know how. I need to use recursion to solve this.

This is my way:

```
function handleDelete (data) {
 return data.filter(t => {
   if (t.children.length) {
     handleDelete(t.children)
    })
   } else {
     return t.id !== '1.2'
  }
})
}
let result = handleDelete(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**delete a node and its descendants**

Here's an effective technique using `flatMap` and mutual recursion<sup>1</sup> -

1. `del` accepts an *array* of nodes, `t`, a query, `q`, and calls `del1` on each node with the query
2. `del1` accepts a *single* node, `t`, a query, `q`, and calls `del` on a node's children

```js
const del = (t, q) =>
  t.flatMap(v => del1(v, q))                  // <-- 1

const del1 = (t, q) =>
  q == t.id
    ? []
    : { ...t, children: del(t.children, q) }  // <-- 2

const data =
  [{id:1,children:[{id:1.1,children:[{id:1.2,children:[]},{id:1.22,children:[]}]}]},{id:2,children:[]}]

const result =
  del(data, "1.2")

console.log(result)
```

In the output, we see node.id `1.2` is removed -

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 1.1,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 1.22,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "children": []
  }
]
```

---

**preserving the descendants**

In the program above, if a `node.id` matches our query, the node and *all* of its descendent children are removed. If we only want to delete the parent node and keep the children, we can make a single modification (`!`) to the program -

```js
const del = (t, q) =>
  t.flatMap(v => del1(v, q))

const del1 = (t, q) =>
  q == t.id
    ? del(t.children, q)                      // <-- !
    : { ...t, children: del(t.children, q) }

const data =
  [{id:1,children:[{id:1.1,children:[{id:1.2,children:[]},{id:1.22,children:[]}]}]},{id:2,children:[]}]

const result =
  del(data, "1")     // <-- delete node.id equal to "1"

console.log(result)
```

Notice how the children for `1` are still included in the output -

```
[
  {
    "id": 1.1,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 1.2,
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "id": 1.22,
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "children": []
  }
]
```

---

**without mutual recursion**

Mutual recursion isn't the only way to do it, but it's the only way to avoid a dynamic type check, such as the one below. In this final revision, we remove a parent and all of its children, as we did in the first program, but this `del` is implemented using a single recursive function -

```js
const del = (t, q) =>
  Array.isArray(t)                             // <-- array
    ? t.flatMap(v => del(v, q))
: Object(t) === t                              // <-- object
    ? q == t.id
      ? []
      : { ...t, children: del(t.children, q) }
: t                                            // <-- neither (noop)


const data =
  [{id:1,children:[{id:1.1,children:[{id:1.2,children:[]},{id:1.22,children:[]}]}]},{id:2,children:[]}]

const result =
  del(data, "1.2")

console.log(result)
```

The output is the same as the first program, where `1.2` and all descendants are removed -

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 1.1,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 1.22,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "children": []
  }
]
```

---

<sup>1.</sup> See this technique used on a different data set in this [related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63765271/633183).
<sup>2.</sup> All programs in this answer produce a new tree. The original input is *not* modified by `del` (or `del1`).

Comment: It took me hours to understand what you meaning. Can you explain more about `Object(t) === t `, how to check is object? The constructor Object(), what does it mean? thanks

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24460874/what-does-objectobj-obj-do#:~:text=2%20Answers&text=Object(obj)%20%3D%3D%3D%20obj%20tests,failing%20also%20for%20strings%2C%20etc.&text=1)%20If%20value%20is%20null,2.1).] I found this link about Object(obj) === obj

Comment: Correct, it's is a way of checking if `t` is an object. However, runtime type checking like `Array.isArray(t)` and `Object(t) === t` is a bit clunky and can sometimes indicate a function is trying to do too many things. The first program avoids type checks by using a combination of smaller functions that each do one thing well.